# Android launchMode and "infinite" SettingsActivities

Tags: android, android-manifest

I have huge problems, to understand the **launchMode** of Android apps or, let's say, I struggle to understand, why `singleTask` isn't the "wanted" or desired default option.

I can't imagine actually any advantage of having or wanting to have more than one active running activity (GUI) instance. It would make sense, of course, if the activity was a sub GUI, where you maybe want to have multiple "tabs", for example in a web browser, file manager, etc. But those are very specific examples, and for a normal app GUI, does it make sense to allow multiple instances of the same GUI frame? On a desktop, there is always one GUI instance, never multiple. One settings instance, one sub settings, and so on. And if you closed the window, you always go back to the one instance of the previous frame.

I noticed this actually really fast, after I implemented a `SettingsActivity (AppCompatPreferenceActivity)` via the default activity template of Android Studio. The problem now was that my app created "infinite" sub setting menus if I went forth/back/forth/back in the settings activity. When I was now pressing the back button, I ran into the this problem:

**submenu1 > menu > submenu1 > menu > submenu2 > menu > submenu2 > menu... > mainacitivity > app closing**

Of course, although this can't be the desired behavior, still it's given as default behavior by Android Studio, and as I understand, is the normal behavior for `launchMode=standard` (or not putting it in the manifest file anyway).

For a `SettingsActivity`, it just doesn't make sense in my understanding to have more than one running instance, and if the user pressed the back button in a sub menu, it should always bring him back to the menu before, and if he's in main menu, into the activity before that.

So how can I change this? or is my whole understanding just wrong? Should a `SettingsActivity` be set as `launchMode=singleTask`? Or how did I get into this infinite loop of back and forth by pressing the back button, if I went into sub menus "too often" before?

I actually read somewhere before, that you should avoid using `launchMode=singleTask`, but I don't know why. In my understanding a `singleTask` would just make more sense, for mostly every situation. How would it make sense to allow multiple instances of any GUI frame...

Hope this isn't a stupid question. I tried to find a satisfying answer to this, but I couldn't find an explanation really to my questions.